# How to update cells of successive matrices using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Score': ['Goal 0', 'Goal 1', 'Goal 2', 'Goal 3'],
             'Goal 0': [0.97,0.02,0,0], 'Goal 1': [0.01,0,0,0], 
             'Goal 2': [0,0,0,0], 'Goal 3': [0,0,0,0]}

        # T1 = 0.02, T2 = 0.01, N = 0.97

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Score', 'Goal 0', 'Goal 1', 'Goal 2', 'Goal 3']) 

v = df.drop('Score', axis=1).as_matrix() 

***for k = 0,1, 2, 3, 4. i=1,2,3,4. j=1,2,3,4.  

     v^0 = ([[0.97, 0.01, 0.  , 0.  ],
             [0.02, 0  , 0.  , 0.  ],
             [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
             [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]]).

     if i==1: v^k[i,j] = ((v^(k-1)[i, j-1]) * T2)
     if j==1: v^k[i,j] = ((v^(k-1)[i-1, j]) * T1)

otherwise v^k[i,j] = (((v^(k-1)[i-1, j]) * T1) + ((v^(k-1)[i, j-1]) * T2) + ((v^(k-1)[i, j]) * N)). ***
```

And the subsequent v^1 is,

```
     ***v^1 = ([0.9409, 0.0097, 0.0001, 0],
             [0.0194, 0.941, 0, 0],
             [0.0004, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0]]) and so .***
```

where v^0 is the dataframe given above. So each cells in v^k is iterated based on v^(k-1).

```
def sweep(v):                    
    for i in range(1, len(v)):
        for j in range(1, len(v)):
            if i == 1: v[i,j] = ((v[i, j-1]) * 0.02) 
            if j == 1: v[i,j] = ((v[i-1, j]) * 0.01)
```

The i and j update first row and first column of each successive matrix. the v here should be the previous matrix (v = v^(k-1)). ***which is what I am struggling to define*** so that given the initial v^0, i want a code that will update each cells of the subsequent matrices. Hence each cell in v^k will have different values from its corresponding v^(k-1) matrix.
eventually I will have v^4. from which I will be able to read the odds of any score. from 0:0 to 3:3

```
    else:
        v[i,j] = (((v[i-1, j]) * 0.02) + ((v[i, j-1]) * 0.97) + ((v[i, j-1]) * 0.01)) 


                            # algorism to update each cell.
                            # one sweep update each row up to one more additional cell from previous. 
                            # for example new V^3 = V^2[i-1,j]*T2 + V^2[i, j-1]*T1 + V^2[i,j]*N. 
                            # Hence no two matrices should have same values. 



for i in range(4):
    sweep(v)
```

*I’m trying to come up with a model that optimises the expected goals figure in a football match. I have divided the match into 4 time portions. The initial probabilities for the two teams (T1 and T2) to score or not score a goal is given and remain the same in each time portions.  The assumption is only one goal can be scored per time portion. 
For each time portion I need to process and build a distribution matrix for the score (T1 score again, T2 score again, No goal) up to the end of the time portion. The matrices above (v^0 and v^1) shows the change from time portion 0, the given probability at the start of the match, and v^1 the distribution from the start to end of time portion 1( v^1).
The resulting probabilities will be used to compare the odds given at the start of the match by a betting co.

***Why isnt this give me the first iteration V^1 above?***

```
def sweep(v_1):
    for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):

                if i == 0: v_tmp[i,j] = v_k[i, j-1] * 0.02
                if j == 0: v_tmp[i,j] = v_k[i-1, j] * 0.01
            else:
                v_tmp[i,j] = (v_k[i-1, j]) * 0.02 + (v_k[i, j-1]) * 0.97 + (v_k[i, j-1]) * 0.01  

        for i in range(4):
            sweep(v_tmp)
```

Comment: Could you describe in words what you're trying to achieve? This gives us some context to interpret your pseudocode, and possibly to refer you to existing solutions.

Comment: @MPA I have just added a paragraph in the post. please have a look.

Comment: 1) In general, you can incrementally update a variable by first generating an intermediate/temporary variable `v_tmp`, in which you store the results of your calculations, which you then copy back into the original `v_k`. In this way you don't alter the values of `v_k` during the intermediate calculations. Is this what you're after? 2) In your code above, your `i` and `j` indices range from 1 to 3. Make sure that you change these to 0 to 2 when you convert your pseudocode into Python code.

Comment: The point you made in 1 is exactly what I want to achieve. As for the second part, I see the error I made but  given that each row has four cells, the indices should range from 0 to 3. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complement my comment above, you can find a minimalistic/silly example of how to use a temporary variable in your calculations below:

```
import numpy as np

v_k = np.array([[0.9409, 0.0097, 0.0001, 0],
                [0.0194, 0.941, 0, 0],
                [0.0004, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0]])

for i in range(4):
    v_tmp = np.zeros_like(v_k)
    v_tmp[0,:] = v_k[1,:]
    v_tmp[1,:] = v_k[0,:]*2
    v_tmp[2,0] = v_k[1,0]
    v_k[:,:] = v_tmp[:,:]
```

You can apply the same pattern to your own code above.

Comment: could you please tell me what I did wrong on the above pattern?

Comment: I believe you're referring to your updated question above. It is best to open this as a new question, instead of building upon an already solved problem. This would lead to a clutter of questions and answers. Open a new question with one specific problem (preferably with a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), notify me by citing @MPA, and we will have a look.